# How do I specify " equals to” whe using XSLT <xsl:when>?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. In my case, suppose am using follwing code:

```
<xsl:when test="(abc/def == 9)">
    N/A
</xsl:when>
```

I have to use **==** condition, but it generates error. There is only != condition accepted. Please let me know is there any provision for **equal to equal to** condition check in XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<xsl:when test="(abc/def = 9)">
```

XSLT knows that there isn't going to be an assignment going on here, so will do a comparison instead